# How to redirect the output from desktop-entry

Tags: .desktop, mono, redirect

I have a program called *prg.exe* written in C#. I want to run this program in mono with an argument (arg1) and redirect the output to a log file called *log.txt*.
If I open a terminal and enter the command:

```
mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt
```

everything works fine.
When the program is finished, the *log.txt* file is created, which contains any error.
Now I want to create a desktop entry called *prg.desktop*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My prg
Comment=some comment
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/openbox.xpm
Exec=mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

If I run *prg.desktop*, the *log.txt* file is **not** created.
The above script is simplified.  In fact, the Exec line contains the full path to the *prg.exe* and *log.txt* files, respectively.
What do I need to do to create the log file?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that directly since that command is executed directly, not via a shell, so I/O redirection doesn't work here.

But it should work to wrap it into a shell call, like this:

```
Exec=sh -c "mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt"
```

Be advised that while this is quite okay to do some debugging, if this is something more permanent, I'd move that into a shell script. Desktop files are not suitable for serious scripting.